# How to change the functionality of key in keyboard using java

Tags: java, keyboard, key

I have a problem in my keyboard that my +/= key is not working (Damaged)

Now I just want to write a service in java

that any other key (let's say ptr sc key) will work same as  +/= key.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Can we write your code for your problem? I dont think so!

Comment: @AlexanderHeim suppose if i pressed ptr sc key it should print the  +

Comment: You don't need to write a program. Just modify your keyboard layout in your OS. E.g. for Windows there is the [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22339).